# PDO query - loop produces duplicate fields?

Tags: php, pdo

The code below is producing duplicate `<td>` elements for each field. I am trying to produce a simple HTML table based on the results of a PDO query. Can anyone tell me why each field is being duplicated?

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM students');

// Print results in a HTML table
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="5">';
foreach($data as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach ($row as $field) {
    echo '<td>' . $field . '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Thanks

Comment: is var_dump($data) has duplicate too?

Comment: I can confirm there are 0 duplicates in the data source.

Comment: My guess would be that each $row looks like this: `array(0 => "SomeValue", "FirstField" => "SomeValue", 1 => "SomeOtherValue", "SecondField" => "SomeOtherValue")`

Comment: What's the point in upvoting a duplicated, easily solvable by manual reading question? Just curious of the reasons.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. You've got a point. Have you got a link for the duplicate question to post for potential future visitors to view? :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you have a problem with the question flag it, don't see how that comment is constructive in any way

Comment: @tomahaug **what's the matter with the link?** Are you familiar with this site controls supposed to help developers to find an answer without the need to complete their question?

Comment: Well, one more friendly warning then. This site is not your personal help center to cherish your laziness. You are supposed to put some efforts in answering your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using the PDO::FETCH_BOTH style.

This will produce an array where the entries are duplicated, once for the column name keys, and once for the integer keys.

See the following for details:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Could you please correct my code so I can see how this is changed? (Not asking you to do my homework, just a newb and doing so will help me learn faster) :]

Comment: I'm not going to do everything for you, but see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

You probably have to add a call to this setting the default fetch mode for your connection.

Comment: Thanks very much - setting it to "FETCH_ASSOC" fixed the duplicate output.

Comment: If you know the field names of the `students` table, instead of looping through the fields, you could simply select the individual columns from the `$row` variable like `$row["StudentName"]`

Answer (score -4):

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM students');

echo "<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info[column1] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<td>".$info[column2] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
echo "</table>
```

Comment: I don't want to have to reference every column name I want to simply show them all using a foreach statement.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array`is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Yes, also I'm using PDO :]